# XSLT conversion with parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone help me with converting the following XML using XSLT.

My XML file is something like:

```
<action>
    <item 
        Category ="shop"
        Id="1234"
        Test="1">
        <message>
            Some message
        </message>
    </item>
    <item 
        Category ="rent"
        Id="3456"
        Actual="1"
        Subdivision="333">
        <message>
            Some shops for rent
        </message>
    </item>
    <item>
    </item>
</action>
```

Now I need to write code in XSLT. If `<message>` is/contains "shops for rent" then I like to get the result/message "some message".

Can you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT outputs the text of the previous `<message>` node if some other `<message>` node contains the text "shops for rent".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="text()" />       <!-- ignores other text content -->

  <xsl:template match="action/item/message[contains(text(),'shops for rent')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::item[1]/message" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is

> Some message

If you would really like to output an [`xsl:message`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_message.asp) instead, surround the `<xsl:value>` with `<xsl:message>`.